# Does insulating an Air Conditioner from inside (for winter) increase chance of damage?

Tags: hvac, air-conditioning, winterizing

I have two window air conditioners that I'd like to seal during winter (Friedrichs).  I'm considering sealing them from inside (with blankets or foam) as they let in a lot of cold air and noise.  However, I'm thinking thermodynamically that means the AC will get a lot colder (since it's not being warmed from inside the house).

I would be installing something like this: [Chillstop from Sustainablesupply.com](https://www.sustainablesupply.com/Chill-StopR-21202-Universal-AC-Cover-2925-W-X-21-H-X-4-D-C2610203?CAWELAID=120205040004833388&CAGPSPN=pla&CAAGID=36154970783&CATCI=pla-354503669703&CATARGETID=120205040004941103&cadevice=c&gclid=Cj0KCQiAurjgBRCqARIsAD09sg98b-tiWlZSNqa7vnRaZZS_wplipzAlIGQ5wisBdgcZYd6-uUTLJ7UaAv_FEALw_wcB)

Does this increase chance of damaging the AC?  Can the AC (I'm thinking in particular the ball bearings) handle being in winter without thermo access to the inside of the house?

These are removable AC's but then I have the problem of storage and sealing in the window casing (it's screwed into the window itself).

Any advice/thoughts much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cold won't harm the AC units the internal components of the compressor are hermedicly sealed. The fan bearings are usually double shielded so there is no problem there. It's really not much different than storing then in an unheated storage space.